# Boot repair disk shows nothing under "Grub location"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

I am running a dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8. The upgrade to Windows 8.1 broke my Ubuntu boot, and boot repair disk failed to fix this.

After receiving some comments to my previous question https://askubuntu.com/questions/599650/boot-repair-disk-failed-to-repair-boot-after-windows-8-1-upgrade I decided that it would probably be easier to change my Ubuntu boot to UEFI.

However, when I use boot repair disk and go to advanced options, there is nothing under "Grub location" which is where I need to do this (the tab is also grayed out, but I am still able to click on it). I do have a working EFI partition, since my preinstalled Windows 8 boots fine.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be in a very tight spot with very little help...

As you haven't given much data on what exactly is wrong with your system (no logs or anything) I can only conclude, based on the data you provided that I would:

1. Boot from a LiveDVD
2. Back up all of [my data](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10695394/) and [config files](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10695426/) *without password* (the last one are mine: Your mileage may vary)
3. Wipe EXT4 partitions and install again in UEFI mode, restore system config files
4. Restore all of my data
5. Re-install all applications, restore application files

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Sorry for not including logs. I included them in the linked question but for some reason I did not think to include them here (they are at http://paste.ubuntu.com/10641386/). It seems from those that boot repair disk (and possibly also grub) is not recognizing my main system partition (sda7) as ext4, even though it is indicated as ext4 in the partition table later in the log.

Comment: I read all that before posting... :-(  I was talking about boot logs and a hex dump of the GPT and similar.